# Mifare Classic 1K reading fail with PN532 chip

Tags: nfc, mifare

I have PN532 chip for NFC and my board is connected to it by SPI. I am shure, that connection is good (Mifare UL totally works). I have some blank 1K classic cards, and there is some troubles.
My moves:

1) Setup PN532 (retries, SAM)

2) search for card by ListPassiveTarget command for ISO14443A cards

3) when card is found, authenticate to some sector (required block_number = sector_number * 4)

4) read data by 4 InDataExchange commands. Required block_number = sector_number * 4 + 0, 1, 2, 3.

5) go to step 3

First sector read is ok, I have some good data. But when I try to read other sector after succesfull authorisation to it, I have an error like I failed authentication.
I tried to read sector 0 (OK), then sector 1..15 read is failed.
I tried to read sector 5 (OK) with all block_num calculations (20,21,22,23 block), then sector 6..15 read is failed.
I tried to remove card from field for a minute, return card to field and repeat reading - and I cant read any sector. Only rebooting helps.
I suppose, that there can be some move between authentications. Typical HALT command is not helping.
Authentication function is tested - wrong keys dont work, wright keys are working.

My code, that dealing with reading:

```
// here we know card type
                // ISO 14443 A MIFARE CLASSIC 1K
                    // repeat polling
                    if( !ListPassiveTarget_14443A_106() )
                    {
                        // no card!
                        NFC_download = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if( !GetGeneralStatus() )
                        {
                            // no card!
                            NFC_download = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {                               
                            if( NFC::Num_Of_Tg != 0 )
                            {
                                // 14443 A Mifare Classic
                                // 16 sectors, 4 blocks in each                     
                                for(u8 sector = 0; sector < 16; sector++)   // for all 16 sectors
                                {
                                // autentificate sector with A key

                                    u8 x = 0;
                                    for(x = 0; (x < 3) && (Autenticated == 0); x++) // loop for keys
                                    {
                                        Autenticated = Try_Mifare_Classic_Key( x, 0, sector );  // try A key
                                                                                                // block = sector*4
                                    }

                                    if( Autenticated != 0 )
                                    {
                                        // send up success and key num
                                        // uart send
                                        if( ((Uart::CommandTX_WPos + 1) & 0x0F) != Uart::CommandTX_RPos  )
                                        {
                                            // ok
                                            Uart::CommandTXBuf[Uart::CommandTX_WPos].Size = 4;  
                                            Uart::CommandTXBuf[Uart::CommandTX_WPos].Buf[0] = AUTH_CLASSIC;
                                            Uart::CommandTXBuf[Uart::CommandTX_WPos].Buf[1] = Autenticated; // key type
                                            Uart::CommandTXBuf[Uart::CommandTX_WPos].Buf[2] = x;            // key number
                                            Uart::CommandTXBuf[Uart::CommandTX_WPos].Buf[3] = sector;       // sector
                                            Uart::CommandTX_WPos = (Uart::CommandTX_WPos + 1) & 0x0F;
                                            Uart::commandSend();                                
                                        }

                                        // read all the sector
                                        Read_Mifare( sector*4 ); 
                                        Read_Mifare( sector*4 + 1); 
                                        Read_Mifare( sector*4 + 2); 
                                        Read_Mifare( sector*4 + 3); 

                                        // reboot card?
                                        //SPI::Wait(5500000); // 1000 ms delay  
                                        //Halt_Mifare();    // halt wont help   
                                        //SPI::Wait(550000);    // 100 ms delay                                     
                                    }                                   
                                }// for sectors
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // no target
                                NFC_download = false;
                                break;
                            }                           
                        }
                    }
```

What can be wrong? I have missed some moves between sector authentications and readings?

Answer (score 0):

Fail in logic. Forgot to clear authentication flag. Now it's working.